# Get attributes of overlapping polygons intersecting a point geometry

Tags: python, geopandas

I am having a multi-polygon shapefile containing 14 overlapping polygons. I am also having a shapefile containing multiple point geometries.

In this case there are some point geometries which are lying in the intersection of the neighboring polygon geometries as shown in the figure.

[image]

What I am looking for is to get the attributes of the overlapping polygons (Polygon1 & Polygon 2) where a particular point geometry lies in the intersection of neighboring overlapping polygons (eg. Polygon1 & Polygon 2).

Till now I have used the following code but it is providing me attribute of one polygon:

```
from geopandas.tools import sjoin
import geopandas as gpd

polygon = gpd.read_file(r"C:\Users\Downloads\poly.shp")
polygon = polygon.to_crs('EPSG:4326') 

points_gdf = gpd.read_file(r"C:\Users\Downloads\points.shp")
points_gdf = points_gdf.to_crs('EPSG:4326') 

pointInPolys = sjoin(points_gdf, polygon, how="inner", op='within')
```

Can someone let me know how to get it.

Comment: @BERA if the point is not lying at the intersection of polygons but it lies in one of the polygon then in that that case I want attribute of only that single polygon. But if the point geometry lies at the intersection of multiple polygons then I want the attributes of all the polygons that encloses that particular point geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic should work, it does with my data.

Point 1 doesnt intersect a polygon so because of inner join it is dropped.

Point 2 intersects polygon 1, so it gets the polygon data joined to it.

Point 3 intersects polygon 2 and 3 so it become two rows, one for each polygon.

[image]

```
import geopandas as gpd

poly = gpd.read_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/op.shp")
point = gpd.read_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/pnts.shp")

#print(poly.columns)
#Index(['polyid', 'geometry'], dtype='object')

#print(point.columns)
#Index(['pointid', 'geometry'], dtype='object')

sj = gpd.sjoin(left_df=point, right_df=poly, how="inner", predicate="within")                     
print(sj)
#    pointid                        geometry  index_right  polyid
# 1        2  POINT (671409.064 6584292.463)            0       1
# 2        3  POINT (671886.925 6583463.769)            1       2
# 2        3  POINT (671886.925 6583463.769)            2       3
```

Comment: Thanks @BERA. Your suggestion helped me. Actually in the output the point geometry indexes were duplicated which went unnoticed of me. Now suppose if I want to add one column ("attribute") in point shapefile which contains the attributes of either single polygon or multiple polygons based on its location then how to do it?

Comment: Nice! You should look to either [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) or [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html). It depends on what you want the output column/columns to lok like. In my example I might want a list of polyids in one column on each point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/how-to-group-dataframe-rows-into-list-in-pandas-groupby then [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) the output to the point df